# How do I change a button image but still select the whole button?

Tags: wpf, image, button

I am trying to make a button in WPF that, when hovered by the mouse, lights up and gets the blue-ish selection around it. I managed the former, but by changing the button image, I apparently override the commands that highlights the button with a blue selection.

This is what I have:

```
<Button Command="DoSomething" Name="button">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="Uniform" Name="buttonImage">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Project;component/Project/Bitmaps/Icon_colour.png" />
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                   <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Project;component/Project/Bitmaps/Icon_grey.png" TargetName="buttonImage"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Is there a way to get the selection back again, while keeping the icon-light-up effect?

Answer (score 1):

You have replaced the default `Button ControlTemplate`, so all you need to do is to 'replace' the missing part(s) from the original `ControlTemplate`. You can find that in the [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Alternatively, you can simply add an `Image` into the `Button.Content` property:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomething, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Image Source="/Project;component/Project/Bitmaps/Icon_colour.png" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not very experienced with WPF to immediately get all the code there. What part of that should I copy where? Everything?

Comment: Good, it should be a good exercise for you. Start with the whole `ControlTemplate` and first get it so your `Button` looks like the default one. *Then* make the changes that you want.

Comment: Haha, well, I don't mind exercises at all, and I'll see how I get on with this. But defining button styles and stuff was a bit beyond the scope of what I had in mind for this.

Comment: What do you mean? You had already defined your own `ControlTemplate` for the `Button`... I tell you what, I'll edit my answer to give you a simpler solution.

Comment: Well, I figured out how to use the `ControlTemplate` within the `Button`, yes. But the example on the website has a massive Style template (and actual place where the Button *is*, if you see what I mean), so I'm having a hard time incorporating it in my project.

Comment: Just copy all of the XAML from that page and paste it into your `Resources` section. The 'magic' part of the `ControlTemplate` is the `ContentPresenter`... this is what is used to display the content and other properties of the `Button`. Please read the 'Remarks' section of the [`ContentPresenter` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) page on MSDN for more help.

Comment: (What didn't help either was that my button was in a ToolBar, where it seems to ignore any or all of the styles that have been defined in the `Resources`)